# outlook script that automatically opens links in emails

Tags: vba, outlook

I am using windows 10 on my pc and use chrome most of the time for outlook. I am trying to get a script that automatically opens a link received in a email. I have found vba scripts but they do not work i keep getting errors. If any of you could help me out with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `HTMLBody` property of the MailItem class to find all hyperlinks there. Then you can use the following method to run Chrome with a link found:

```
Sub LaunchInChrome (url as String)
  Dim chromePath As String
  chromePath = """C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"""
  Shell (chromePath & " -url " & url)
End Sub
```